# Why my ENUM value show 0 insted of showing default value of type text

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I am a little bit confussing and try to understand where the error is.
I am want to assign default value to ticket when User submit it should by defaul be `Open` and show in Index Page as `Open` but insted I get 0 in Index page.

[image]

Here is value from my `ENUM`

```
 public enum TicketStatus
    {
        Otvoren = 1,
        NaCekanju = 2,
        Zatvoren = 3
    }
```

And I assign default value to my Model Propery

```
public TicketStatus Status { get; set; } = TicketStatus.Otvoren;
```

DataTable render section

```
function loadDataTable() {
    dataTable = $('#tblData').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Manager/Ticket/GetAll"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "description", "width": "15%" },
            { "data": "dateAndTime", "width": "15%" },
            { "data": "ticketType.name", "width": "15%" },
            //{ "data": "user.name", "width": "15%" },
            //{ "data": "client.name", "width": "15%" },
            { "data": "status", "width": "15%" },
            { "data": "answered", "width": "15%" },
            {
                "data": "id",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return `
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <a href="/Manager/Discussion/OpenDiscussion/${data}" class="btn btn-primary text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                                    <i class="fas fa-comments"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="/Manager/Ticket/Details/${data}" class="btn btn-success text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                                    <i class="fas fa-info"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                           `;
                }, "width": "20%"
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

Does anyone know where I made mistake ? What is wrong with this ?
Sorry I am begginer in asp.net core and maybe qestion look stupid but I spent hours and hours to understand what is wrong here.

Cheers !

**UPDATE**

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetAll()
        {

            var obj = _unitOfwork.Ticket.GetAll(includeProperties: "TicketType,ApplicationUser");
            return Json(new { data = obj });
        }
```

Here is Create Action where everything start

```
 public IActionResult Upsert(int? Id)
        {

            TicketVM ticketVM = new TicketVM()
            {
                Ticket = new Ticket(),
                TicketTypeList = _unitOfwork.TicketType.GetAll().Select(i => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = i.Name,
                    Value = i.Id.ToString()
                })
            };

            if (Id == null)
            {
                return View(ticketVM);
            }


            ticketVM.Ticket = _unitOfwork.Ticket.Get(Id.GetValueOrDefault());

            if (ticketVM.Ticket == null)
            {
                NotFound();
            }
            return View(ticketVM);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Upsert(TicketVM ticketVM)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (ticketVM.Ticket.Id == 0)
                {
                    _unitOfwork.Ticket.Add(ticketVM.Ticket);
                }
                else
                {
                    _unitOfwork.Ticket.Update(ticketVM.Ticket);
                }
                _unitOfwork.Save();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(ticketVM);
        }
```

Comment: provide the relevant code

Comment: @viveknuna What kind of relevant code do you need ? I don't have anthing else

Comment: If a new instance of your model is created, it will have the default value, however it seems that you are somehow assigning it a value (either directly or by parsing) but I can't help you where this happened because your posted question is missing where you created and used the model

Comment: If you are using Newtonsoft JSON you can use `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))] 
public enum TicketStatus`

Comment: The issue is that in your GetAll method when it returns your model the model gets JSON serialized. By default enum values get serialized by their numeric value. The simplest solution would be Prashanths answer to force serialization by name if you use NewtonSoft JSON, which would be the case until ASP.NET Core 2. Otherwise you could define your status property as a string and assign it as `model.Status = TicketStatus.Otvoren.ToString()`. You can later convert a string to its enum value by using Enum.Parse.

Comment: I belive that I need pass this value to my controller

Answer (score 0):

I found where the error is. Inside my controller where Crete Action Happened I need to add something like this:

```
ticketVM.Ticket.Status = TicketStatus.Otvoren.ToString();
```